# Обращение к элементу RecyclerView.ViewHolder из AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, view, android-asynctask

Я создал определенный view элемент, код ниже:

```
public class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView personPhoto;
    ImageButton personLike;

    PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        personLike = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_like);
    }
}
```

В методе onBindViewHolder идет установка значений в элемент personViewHolder.personPhoto:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) { Glide.with(personViewHolder.personAge.getContext()).load(dogs.get(i).photoId).into(personViewHolder.personPhoto);}
```

Далее в AsyncTask выполняется нужная мне задача и в методе onPostExecute я хочу произвести установку изображения в элемент personViewHolder.personLike:

```
public final class like_set extends AsyncTask<Integer , Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer ... arg) {
        String res = "1";
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if ( result.equals("1"))
        {Glide.with(personViewHolder.personLike.getContext()).load(R.drawable.like_red).into(personViewHolder.personLike);
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Но возникает ошибка "Cannot resolve symbol personViewHolder" при обращении к строчке personViewHolder в onPostExecute.

Как можно из этого метода установить картинку в мой view элемент PersonViewHolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot resolve symbol personViewHolder

Еще бы не писал, он находится очевидно в другом классе. Либо делайте свой `AsyncTask` вложенным классом или передавайте `personViewHolder` в конструкторе `AsyncTask`